# Python can't access file on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I'm trying to run my code in Python through Windows 10 cmd like this:
`python3 flir_image_extractor.py -avg -i 'C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\example.jpg'`

The first thing it does is checking if the input path it's a file:

```
if not os.path.isfile(flir_img_filename):
            raise ValueError("Input file does not exist or this user don't have permission on this file")
```

And that error is exactly what I'm getting when running the cmd command. My file exists and is located at the given path ("this pc" and "desktop", respectivelly), and explorer's set to show file extension:
[image]

I tried many other ways to input the path, as:

```
'C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\example.jpg'
'C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/example.jpg'
r'C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\example.jpg'
```

Nothing worked so far.

This code works perfectly on Ubuntu, but I need to make sure it works on Windows in order to use PyInstaller for this OS. I'm using Python 3.9.5

You can check the complete code I'm using at https://github.com/Nervengift/read_thermal.py?fbclid=IwAR3FDfsIgSF5k-EKWSrAbnWO1oM-vWiBgDPrL3iOSSfUSexhlP1_BeVTUz4
. I added only the -avg option to match the use I want, but mimicking the other ones.

I thank you in advance.

EDIT:

I "coppyed as path" the file as sugested, and now there's the output:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\venv_holder>python3 flir_image_extractor.py -avg -i "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\example.jpg"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\venv_holder\flir_image_extractor.py", line 232, in <module>
    fie.process_image(args.input)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\venv_holder\flir_image_extractor.py", line 53, in process_image
    if self.get_image_type().upper().strip() == "TIFF":
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\venv_holder\flir_image_extractor.py", line 66, in get_image_type
    meta_json = subprocess.check_output(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 505, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
```

Last line reads "System can't find the specified file"

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the path is correct? You can shift+right-click the file in Explorer and choose "Copy as path" to be sure.

Comment: Also, the `flir_image_extractor.py` in your link does not accept an `-avg` parameter...

Comment: Correct, I added that parameter to work the same way to the to the `-p` one, just calling a different function over the collected image array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on windows, do not enclose your command line arguments in single quotes, they are passed as literals to your application. Either use doube quotes, or - if your path does not contain spaces - don't use quotes at all.

You probably could have figured that out yourself if you'd print out the filename as part of the error message.

Also: single quotes will not prevent a command line argument from being split if it contains spaces.